# ¿Como calcular el dominio y rango de una funcion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Buen día.

Tengo una aplicación web en la cual en base a una función debo presentar el dominio y rango de dicha función, por ejemplo de la función 2X+3 obtener el dominio y el rango.No se si exista una librería para este tipo de situaciones.
He buscado en librerías para matemáticas como math.js pero no encuentro información sobre ello.De antemano gracias.

Comment: Por favor agrega una breve descripción de lo que has buscado/investigado.

Comment: @Rubén he estado googleando pero la verdad no he econtrado nada, he buscado en librerias para matemanticas como math.js pero no encuentro informacion sobre ello

Comment: Agrega eso a la pregunta, indicando los principales términos de búsqueda que has usado.

Comment: Te dejo el link a la documentacion de las funciones de math.js, aunque como han dicho más arriba, yo tampoco he conseguido encontrar la respuesta exacta. http://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Los números en javascript están limitados a números flotantes de doble precisión, definidos en el estándar [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point). Significa que no soporta números menores a `-9007199254740991` ni mayores a `9007199254740991`. Por lo tanto, no abarca el dominio de los números enteros. Si haces

```
console.log(9007199254740992 === 9007199254740993)
```

devuelve `true`, lo que es incorrecto.

La precisión de un número de punto flotante de doble precisión alcanza hasta 16 dígitos, por lo que tampoco abarca el dominio de los números reales. Si haces

```
console.log(1.0000000000000001 === 1.000000000000000111)
```

Nuevamente devuelve `true`.

Finalmente, tampoco soporta números complejos ni imaginarios:

```
Math.sqrt(-4)
```

Devuelve `NaN`.

Hay herramientas online que pueden calcular dominio y rango, como WolframAlpha:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=b0160688b805d84769cebe1afb71895

Pero si quieres hacerlo tú mismo, tendrías que hacer un parseador polinomial que dividiera la definición de función en un árbol de sintaxis y evaluara, por ejemplo:

- Si hay un componente con la forma `1/(x -a)` el dominio excluye los números reales donde x es igual que a, y el rango excluye los números reales donde y es igual a cero.
- Si hay un componente con la forma `√(x-a)`, el dominio excluye los reales donde X es menor que A, y el rango incluye todos los números reales mayores a cero.
- Funciones como seno y coseno tienen como dominio todos los números reales, y como rango todos los reales entre -1 y 1.
- La función exponencial tiene como dominio a todos los reales, y como rango todos los reales mayores a cero
- La función logaritmo tiene como dominio todos los reales mayores a cero y como rango todos los reales.

En la medida que el polinomio tenga varias de estas funciones, sus rangos y dominios son definidos por la intersección (no la unión) de los rangos y dominios de cada componente.